# What is the meaning of error obtained in dblquad integration using scipy?

Tags: python, scipy, numerical-integration

I would like to know the meaning of the error as given by different Python integration routines, e.g. dblquad. Since we do not know the exact 
integration value, how is the estimate of error calculated? What is the reference? In some of my calculations I see that increasing the limit of integration takes the error to extremely high values. Since it is just an estimate of error, is it at all advisable to rely on such a result?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Short answer

> is it at all advisable to rely on such a result?

In most cases, yes. But if you think the integration routine is behaving strangely and you don't trust its output, do try to change the approach: for example, divide the region of integration into parts, integrate over each part separately and see if the results add up.

#### Explanation

In numerical integration, one estimates the error by using two methods to compute the integral (or the same method with two step sizes), and considering the difference between the results. [Deep within Fortran source](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/cc9f6b203742db6e5ec30a6a15f4a2c292e21ffb/scipy/integrate/quadpack/dqk21.f#L176) of SciPy's quadpack routines we find

```
abserr = dabs((resk-resg)*hlgth)
```

where resg is the result of the 10-point Gauss formula, and resk is the result of the 21-point Kronrod formula. See the Wikipedia article [Gauss–Kronrod quadrature formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%E2%80%93Kronrod_quadrature_formula) for the mathematical meaning of these. (The `hlgth` is half the length of the integral of integration; the length is here due to scaling.)

Actually, the formula I quoted is not the final error estimate, it's a very crude first approach to it. Two lines later  we see

```
abserr = resasc*(0.2d+03*abserr/resasc)**1.5d+00)
```

which is exactly what the Wikipedia article states:

> The recommended error estimate is (200*|gauss - kronrod|)<sup>1.5</sup>

This kind of estimate of the absolute error is not **guaranteed** to bound the difference between the computed and actual integral (the latter being unknown). The "recommended" estimate tends to work in practice, and there's some mathematical justification for the exponent 1.5 (the order of convergence of the method) but we never know if it really covers the actual error.

After all, the function was only evaluated at finitely many points within its domain. For all we know, it could happen to be 0 at those points and something huge elsewhere, at the points where the integration routine didn't look.

#### Example

Here is an integral of a simple-looking function which is evaluated incorrectly:

```
from scipy.integrate import quad
import numpy as np
quad(lambda x: np.exp(-x**2), -1e2, 1e3)
```

returns `(4.176612573788305e-60, 7.896357364711954e-60)`. The actual integral is about 1.77 (the square root of pi). The error estimate 8e-60 is completely wrong, as is the value 4e-60. The reason is that this function is localized near 0, and the interval of integration is [-100, 1000], which is much larger. The `quad` algorithm did not happen to sample the function at any points with sizable values, so it proceeded on the idea that it's pretty much zero everywhere.

Comment: Thanks for explaining and quoting the abserr formula. My integrand is very complex and is evaluated, say, for 40k points in the domain [0, 5e9](a double integral from 0 - inf). Where 5e9 is a substitute for infinity. I get errors which can be as high as 1e6/1e11. That's why I want to know if it can be relied upon. I don't get any overflow errors but the more I increase the limit (say to 5e11) the higher the error becomes(1e11 from 1e6).

Comment: wrt the integral value which is supposed to be very high, say, 1e21, the error looks small (1e6/1e11). do you think in that case the error is ok?

Comment: Very large limit of integration is likely a problem; I suspect the numbers you get are bogus.  I included an example of such a thing happening in my answer.  For all I know, your integral may be divergent. If not, a change of variable might help (maybe polar coordinates would work better?).  Or, a dyadic approach: integrate over the region of size 2^k for different values of k; compare the results. This is not an issue I can work out in comments.

Comment: Thanks for the example and your comments. I get your point. I will try to specify the domain of integration as precisely as possible. The integral is already in polar coordinates. I haven't used the dyadic approach but I will check it.

Comment: If it's already in polar, the dyadic decomposition is convenient: integrate over ranges 0<r<1, 1<r<2, 2<r<4, 4<r<8, etc,  and continue adding the results until the integrals becomes really small.  The sum should be a good approximation to the total integral.

Comment: Ok. I will try it. Thanks!

Comment: Ok. I'll test the same for different functions. If I see the same result then I'll ask a general question. Thanks.